# Serialization in the Hazelcast IMap

Tags: java, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

*I'm trying to load data into IMap inside jet pipeLine stage I'm getting the error*

*Here is my code*

```
    public static Pipeline pipeLineStage(JetInstance jet) {
        Pipeline pipeLine = Pipeline.create();

        BatchStage<DataModel> dbValue = pipeLine.readFrom(Sources.jdbc(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?user=postgres&password=root",

                        "SELECT  id1, id2, id3, id4\r\n"
                        + " FROM public.tbl_test where id1='3'",

                resultSet -> new DataModel(resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4))));

        dbValue.filter(model -> model.getId2().equals("person"))
                .map(model -> JsonUtil.mapFrom(model.getObject_value())).map(map -> {
                    IMap<Object, Object> map1 = jet.getMap("map1");
                    map1.put("employee_id", map.get("id"));
                    return map;
                }).writeTo(Sinks.logger());

        return pipeLine;

    }
```

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "mapFn" must be serializable
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:203)
```

*If I store the data in a normal `Map` I'm not getting any error and  getting error only if I store in `IMap` Object and In the above code I'm using model class i,e `DataModel` and that implements `public class DataModel implements Serializable {}`..... Any suggestions would also be helpful.. Thanks *

Comment: Could you please share the error? Also, you shouldn't put data during the `map()` transform step but during the `writeTo()` final step.

Comment: You can't access `jet` (or any other resource) from within code that executes on the Jet cluster. To access a Hazelcast map, use the provided `mapUsingIMap` or `mapUsingService`.

Comment: I want to put key and value in in IMap? I don't think mapUsingIMap will support that.. or Can you give some examples for that?

Comment: If you want to write to map, you need the IMap sink. From the mapping step emit the entry you want to insert and add `.writeTo(Sinks.map(...))`.

Comment: This code sample illustrates the approach to process data using Jet Pipeline, storing results to IMap: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/master/examples/imdg-connectors/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/examples/imdg/MapSourceAndSinks.java

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have configured a serialization factory by the name of mapFn which requires serialization. Simply add implements Serializable to the class definition.